# Pause a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to pause a for loop in javascript/jquery?

I have a `$.each`, that runs through a 63 long array, which have a `for` inside, which have another `for`, which have yet another `for` in it (Makes `each`>`for`>`for`>`for`), now each  of the `for` loops through the array, this makes 63^4 (Equals 15752961) different combinations, and that takes time...

Sooo, is it possible to pause it 2sec, at 2k combinations?

Reason why I want to pause the loop, is to unlock the UI...

Code:

```
var $arr = ["","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
len = $arr.length,
l = 0,
$("body").delay(1000).show(0, function(){
    $.each($arr, function(index, val){ // 63
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){ // 3969
            for(var j = 0; j < len; j++){ // 250047
                for(var k = 0; k < len; k++){ // 15752961
                    thing = val+i+j+k;
                    l++;
                    $("#loading").text(l+"/15752961");
                    console.log(l+"/15752961");
                    $("<div>"+thing+"</div><br />").prependTo("body");                                  
                }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Ps. If someone think, they could clear up my question, please do so :D

**/* EDIT */**
If I try to run this server side, I get a server error, both if I use `foreach` or `for`

```
$smaa = range("a","z");
$store = range("A","Z");
$tal = range("0","9");
$arr = array_merge($smaa, $store, $tal);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){ // 62
    for($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++){ // 3844
        for($k = 0; $k < $count; $k++){ // 238328
            for($l = 0; $l < $count; $l++){ // 14776336
                $finish[] = $arr[$i].$arr[$j].$arr[$k].$arr[$l];
            }
            $finish[] = $arr[$i].$arr[$j].$arr[$k];
        }
        $finish[] = $arr[$i].$arr[$j];
    }
$finish[] = $arr[$i];
}

foreach($arr as $first){ // 62
    $finish[] = $first;
    foreach($arr as $second){ // 3844
        $finish[] = $first.$second;
        foreach($arr as $third){ // 238328
            $finish[] = $first.$second.$third;
            foreach($arr as $fourth){ // 14776336
                $finish[] = $first.$second.$third.$fourth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, that I **don't** use both on the same time

Comment: And why do you need to pause it? What is the practical value for that?

Comment: You can do ["chunk" looping / batch processing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10344560/575527) to prevent the UI from freezing during the long loop.

Comment: 2 second pauses every 2k records would be ~4.5 hours x.x

Comment: That seems excessive nesting: each > for > for > for. I don't think I've ever seen that, and I've been developing for 15 years. =( Perhaps if you post some code, that would help.

Comment: If you're iterating through the same 63 long array nested four levels deep, it does make me wonder what problem you're trying to solve!

Comment: Do you mean you'd like the thread to yield every few seconds to unlock the UI?

Comment: You need something like a queue and process it asynchronously. See [Asynchronous for cycle in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript).

Comment: Why are you scanning through the same array so many times?  Convert the data to some other structure the first time through, such as a hash or tree, and only scan the data once.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Yea, it's something like that, that I need :D

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer But, can't see how I'm gonna do it? I mean, I do a it in a `each`, and 3 `for`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but hopefully you will get the idea. Truthfully, this is something you probably should be handling on the server-side, or doing once and storing the output in the code.

```
var $arr = ["","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],
len = $arr.length,
l = 0,
paused = false,
writer = '',
pauseAt = 2000;

$("body").delay(1000).show(0, function(){

    function killForTwoSeconds(){ //function to timeout loop
         paused = true; //set to true to kill loop
         $('body').append(writer); //write to body only on pause (fewer writes to dom = faster script)
         setTimeout(function(){ // wait for 2 seconds
              paused = false;
              loopIt(); // re-run loop
         },2000);
    }

    function loopIt(){
        $.each($arr, function(index, val){ 
            for(var i = l; i < len; i++){ 
                for(var j = l; j < len; j++){ //loops now start at l instead of 0 so when loop restarts it restarts at the right place
                    for(var k = l; k < len; k++){ 
                        if(l % pauseAt === 0){ // if l is divisible by 2000 kill 
                            killForTwoSeconds();
                        }
                        if(!paused){ //if not paused add item to writer
                            thing = val+i+j+k;
                            l++;
                            $("#loading").text(l+"/15752961");
                            console.log(l+"/15752961");
                            writer = "<div>"+thing+"</div><br />";                                  
                        }else if(index === len-1 && k === len-1){
                            $('body').append(writer); //final write
                        }else{
                            return false; // if paused return false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried to do it serverside, but it's gonna crash... :/

Comment: Why not do it client side one time, send the output to the console, and copy and paste it into the js file?

Comment: If I do try to run a loop (Either `for` or `foreach`), more than 2 times, it's gonna crash D: (Check my question again, updated it)

Comment: why run it more than 2 times?

Comment: Ment, that if I loop through all 4 of them, it's gonna crash, but if I only run 2 of them, it works...

Comment: I've done much bigger loops on the server side, you might just need to bump up server resources.

Comment: So somehthing might be wrong with my script? But can't see what?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with it, you are just asking alot of the cpu.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's no possible to "pause" a for loop, and anyway it will not make it faster.

Don't use it here, but take a look at [`window.setTimeout(fn, delay)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: But, I only have one function?

Comment: you absolutely can stop a loop, you return false to a wrapper function.

Comment: @Fresheyeball. He wants to pause not to stop. You can return anything you want to stop, but how would you continue? and let's you found a way (it can be done with a lot of spaghetti code) it will only cause the code to be slower. BTW: `return false` is a [jQuery thing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10729215/601179).

Comment: pausing inherently makes things slower, but I can understand why someone would want to. You can then restart it in a manner similar to the one in my answer, you rerun the loop but start the index at the where it left off last time.

Comment: @Fresheyeball. As you wish, my answer is still no, because this isn't solving anything. You just break the loop, increase the overhead, and start the loop again. I can't see any benefits here.

Comment: Even if you don't see a benefit, doesn't make it impossible. Your answer is still inaccurate.

Comment: There are plenty of good reasons to pause a loop, even if this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Fresheyeball. I don't want to have a comments discussion, anyway, it does answer **this** question, if you don't like the answer, you can downvote it, this is why we have voting system here...

Answer (score 1):

No.

However, you can use something like this:

```
(function() {
    var i=0, j=0, k=0, timer;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        // loop body here
        k++;
        if( k >= max_k) {
            k = 0;
            j++;
            if( j >= max_j) {
                j = 0;
                i++;
                if( i >= max_i) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }
        }
    },1);
})();
```

I'm not sure how to integrate that with `$.each`, you may have to do it in plain JavaScript. But this code will basically run the loop as fast as possible while still redrawing.

Comment: Actually you might want to put one or two of the loops inside the `loop body here` part, otherwise this will take a minimum of 1,575.2961 seconds, or about half an hour.

Comment: Even using setTimeout won't prevent the issue he/she is trying to avoid, namely the processing slowing down the UI. Web workers could be the proper solution but aren't supported in older versions of IE. But even using setTimeout won't stop the main thread from being dominated by generating that list for quite a few seconds. It just inserts in some points that something else *could* "interrupt" the calculations but in practice the UI still basically locks up.