# Disable Esc key to close panel on jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

According to jQuery Mobile's documentation:

> "Clicking the link that opened the panel, swiping left or right, or tapping the Esc key will close the panel. (...) By default, panels can also be closed by clicking outside the panel onto the page contents."

http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/

The same documentation shows how to turn off "swipe to close" and "close by clicking outside".

But how to disable closing by the `Esc` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$("body").on("keyup", function(e){
    if (e.which === 27){
        return false;
    } 
});
```

This will disable the escape key from closing a panel when one is open. This might interfere with other functions, and you probably could specify what element you want the event attached to. You can read more on `return false` **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729198/what-does-return-false-do)**.

I made a **[very simple and lazy example](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/4evS6/)** of it working.

Comment: I wanted to disable it so I can use it for something else, and I was afraid that doing something like this would ruin my other function. But actually it didn't since I have another listener there :) Thanks

Comment: You could also remove the functionality right from jQM, if you were so daring.