# jQuery submit not working when we write return false after it

Tags: jquery

jQuery submit function is not working in following case and when I remove return false from this code then it starts working.

**JavaScript**

```
function insertQuotit() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url')?>/quotitinsert.php",
        type: "post",
        data: jQuery('#quotitInsert').serialize(),
        success: function (res) {

            jQuery("#quotitInsert").submit();

        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" id="quotitInsert" action="http://www.abc.net" >
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="submit"  onclick="return insertQuotit();"/>
```

Comment: The return value of an event handler determines whether or not the default browser behavior should take place as well. by using `return false;` you are preventing default behavior. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729198/what-does-return-false-do

Answer (score 0):

You're clicking on a submit button, whose default behavior is to submit a form and reload the page.

By using `return: false`, you prevents the browser from performing that default action.

Comment: what is the solution? i can't remove return false because on form submit i have to perform 2 actions. when first action completes only then i will submit form as you can see ajax request when i submit form

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.location = "http://www.abc.net" ;
```

instead of

```
jQuery("#quotitInsert").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="submit" />
```

To

```
<input type="button" />
```

and remove `return false`

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this in your form field.
**`onsubmit="return false;"`**

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="quotitInsert" action="http://www.abc.net" >
```

this should prevent form from getting submitted.